# Ellipse rotating around multiple axis'

Tags: integration

The ellipse given by the equation x^2/16 + y^2/9 =  is rotated around the x-axis and the y-axis.

I need to use the disk and the shell method to compute the volume!

I know the formulas for the disk/shell. Could i just use the disk method as it rotates around the x axis and then use the shell for the rotation around the y-axis? cause the volume would be the same either way right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your equation is equal to 1. The volumes are not the same. The x axis rotation has a max radius of half the minor axis. The y axis rotation has a max radius of half the major axis. These volumes look quite different.

If you take a thin strip centered on the x axis and rotate it around the x axis, you get a wire. If you rotate it around the y axis you get a disc.